# introduction package with composer (v. 10)

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

i tried to install the introduction package in a fresh installation of TYPO3 10.

- composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution => OK.
- Admin Tool till the end => OK.
- Login in the empty Backend => OK, all looks great.
- composer require typo3/cms-introduction
- ./vendor/bin/typo3 extension:activate bootstrap_package => Message OK
- ./vendor/bin/typo3 extension:activate introduction => no message

=> no page tree in the backend.

All extensions are installed but the import script of the introduction package did not run. I tried to deinstall the introduction package in the extension manager and reinstall it but the result is a grey screen in the extension manager.

Seems impossible to install the introduction package with composer.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please follow the install instructions at https://docs.typo3.org/p/typo3/cms-introduction/4.1/en-us/Installation.html. The database must be empty to get it done. Let the install wizard create an empy page and then follow the instructions mentioned before. Use the base-dist for the initial install.

Comment: Well ... i did exactly so. Tried it twice with fresh folders and databases.It did not work. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I did. By the way you have also to delete the whole database or in minimum the sys_registry table to allow another import.